# How to change the background of the custom alert dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom alert dialog, in which i set a list view and its background is white.

But i am getting a view like this.

[image]

This is the screenshot which is fits entire screen.

```
 Dialog d = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);       
        CustomDialogListAdapter customDialogAdapter;
        ListView customList = new ListView(context);
        customList.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        customList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        customDialogAdapter = new CustomDialogListAdapter(context,PaymentInfo.creditCardTypes, type);
        customList.setAdapter(customDialogAdapter);
        customList.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        d.setContentView(customList);
        d.show();
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: post the XML layout which you have used for creating custom alert dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext(); 
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); 
dialog.show();
```

the above code will generate a transparent dialog box. So your listviews background will be the only background for the dialog box.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your useful answer, still i am getting one problem in this. The dialog is coming full screen. how to avoid that. I have updated the code.

Comment: Here, size of the dialog is depending on the size of listview. We can try limiting the height of listview. I haven't tried this, but here's an idea to limit the size of listview: 

`ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = customList.getLayoutParams();`
`params.height = 300;`
`customList.requestLayout();`

here the height is specified in "px"

Comment: hi, can u please add a screenshot

Comment: I could get dis work only by having a xml layout for the dialog. Here is the code:
 
`Dialog d = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);`
`d.setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);`
`CustomDialogListAdapter customDialogAdapter;`
`ListView customList=(ListView) d.findViewById(R.id.list_view);`
`customDialogAdapter = new CustomDialogListAdapter(context,PaymentInfo.creditCardTypes, type);`
`customList.setAdapter(customDialogAdapter);`
`customList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`
`customList.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`
`d.show();`

Comment: Here is code of list_layout.xml :
`<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">`
 `<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"></ListView>`

`</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: android:layout_height="match_parent" i can't use this, I am developing fro android 2.1. and i am not coding xml file for list view i am creating it programatically.

Comment: you can use "fill_parent" instead of "match_parent". Also, I have tried the programmatic way, however was unable to make it look the you wished.

Comment: can you please post me the programmatic approach for this solution. I tried but not working. Please post me the code. Thank you for you support.

Comment: Try dis, working perfectly at my end:  
`Dialog d = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);`
`RelativeLayout listLayout= new RelativeLayout(context);`
`CustomDialogListAdapter customDialogAdapter;`
`ListView customList = new ListView(context);`
`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`
`param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);`
`customDialogAdapter = new CustomDialogListAdapter(context, PaymentInfo.creditCardTypes, type);`
`customList.setAdapter(customDialogAdapter);`

Comment: `customList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`
`customList.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`
`listLayout.addView(customList, param);`
`d.setContentView(listLayout);`
`d.show();`

Answer (score 1):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder screenDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidCaptureScreen.this);
    screenDialog.setTitle("Captured Screen");



    TextView TextOut = new TextView(AndroidCaptureScreen.this);
    TextOut.setText(EditTextIn.getText().toString());
    LayoutParams textOutLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextOut.setLayoutParams(textOutLayoutParams);

    ImageView bmImage = new ImageView(AndroidCaptureScreen.this);
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(bmScreen);
    LayoutParams bmImageLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    bmImage.setLayoutParams(bmImageLayoutParams);

    LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(AndroidCaptureScreen.this);
    dialogLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    dialogLayout.addView(TextOut);
    dialogLayout.addView(bmImage);
    screenDialog.setView(dialogLayout);

    screenDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

         }
        });
    screenDialog.show();
   }
```

Comment: I don't have a tittle or a button in my custom layout. The layout params which you have defined here I have done same in xml style. Still the output remains same... :(

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent view layout and set its background :)

Comment: probably he referes at something like:            `dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);`

Answer (score 0):

This will make it work :

in the Listview add this

android:cachecolorhint="#00000000"

Comment: #00000000 is the value for transparent.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ,i got the desire output by using this code snippet :

```
Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(Activity.this);
ListView modeList = new ListView(Activity.this);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);


 String[] stringArray = new String[] { "No results" };

  ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity.this, R.layout.list_main, R.id.item_subtitle, stringArray);
  modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

 builder.setView(modeList);
 dialog2 = builder.create();
 dialog2.show();
```

And in the list_main.xml ,set the background color white :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="7dp"
android:background="#ffffff">
</LinearLayout>
```

For custom adapter :

```
    builder.setTitle(" title");
            MySimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(Activity.this, data , R.layout.list_main, 
                    new String[] { "name", "distance" ,"phone","web"}, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle ,R.id.item_subtitle1 ,R.id.item_subtitle2});
            modeList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I am having my own custom view to load into the list for that i have my own adapter. How can i do with that..? as you are using ArrayAdapter. I tried your approach with my adapter but its not working.

Comment: I also used this for custom adapter only...just replace ArrayAdapter with your own adapter..check the edited answer..